# Bundler renders styles merged and minified in Debug mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-optimization

Using VS 2013 Update 3 I am creating a new ASP MVC 5 app.

Changing nothing, running this web app with F5, and monitoring the http trafic with fiddler I am seeing that one merged and minified CSS travelling. Debug mode if true in web.config.

I would like the distinct not minified CSS in my browsers developer tools.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your bundle config

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Comment: Thx. (Why is this not in a conditional #if DEBUG in project template that's a puzzler. Zillions of people rewrites this zillon times...  )